# Can we build an native client app in C++ which can run on chrome OS?

Tags: chromium, google-chrome-os

Can we build an native client app in C++ which can run on chrome OS?
I have checked native client app documentation it says it will be soon supporing ChromeOS. Currently it is supporting for chrome browser on windows and MAC.
I want is it possible on Chromium OS??
Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can.

See the app "PNaCl Examples" in the Chrome Web Store. It runs on my Chromebook with Version 31.0.1650.35 beta. I think PNaCl is built-in as of Version 31. However, NaCl is much older, and probably works with even earlier versions.